# vhdl subtract std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to substract 2 std logic vector and get error

```
p2 <= p1(11 downto 0)- idata(11 downto 0);
```

> Error (10327): VHDL error at sub.vhd(32): can't determine definition of operator ""-"" -- found 0 possible definitions

I already tried to add `use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all` or  `use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all` or both and already tried 
`p2 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(p1(11 downto 0)) - unsigned(idata(11 downto 0)));`

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
--use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;
--use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity sub is 

port (  
    clk         : in    std_logic;
    rst         : in    std_logic;
    --en            : in    std_logic;  
    idata    : in    std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
    odata    : out  std_logic_vector (11 downto 0)  
);
end sub;

architecture beh of sub is
signal p1,p2 :std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
begin
    process (clk, rst) 
        begin
            if (rst = '1') then
                odata  <= "000000000000";
            elsif (rising_edge (clk)) then  
                    p1 <= idata;
                    p2 <= p1(11 downto 0)- idata(11 downto 0);
                    --p2 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(p1(11 downto 0)) - unsigned(idata(11 downto 0)));

            end if;             
    end process;
    odata<=p2;
end beh;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `std_logic_vector` type is just an array of `std_logic`, and does not by itself have any numerical interpretation, thus the error when trying to apply numeric operations like minus (`-`).

Don't use the Synopsys non-standard `std_logic_signed/unsigned/arith` packages.

**VHDL-2002**: use the `unsigned` type in the standard `ieee.numeric_std` package to convert a `std_logic_vector` to a `unsigned` representation, which allows use of numeric operations like minus.   Code like:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
p2 <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(p1(11 downto 0)) - unsigned(idata(11 downto 0)));
```

**VHDL-2008**: use the standard `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned` package to convert a `std_logic_vector` to a `unsigned` representation, which allows use of numeric operations like minus.   Code like:

```
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;
...
p2 <= p1(11 downto 0) - idata(11 downto 0);
```

Btw. check out this [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vhdl+can%27t+determine+definition+of+operator) for similar issues.

Comment: Also the -2008 revision of the VHDL standard incorporates a numeric_std_unsigned package which provides unsigned operation wrappers for std_logic_vector.

Comment: Updated answer with VHDL-2008 compliant code using the `numeric_std_unsigned` package.

Comment: Is 2008 not backwards compat with 2002? I can't get the 2002 answer above to compile, complains no declarations for operator+, even though I imported `ieee.numeric_std.all`.

Comment: The construction in the VHDL-2002 code above is usable when compiling for VHDL-2008 also, and is widely used since code is generally not rewritten when moving from VHDL-2002 to VHDL-2008 compile.